# How to pass in Python?

Tags: python, exception, scrape

I have a problem to do a scrape with Python. I need to collect patent data for multiple firms, but when a firms' patent is available my code does not move to the next item on the list. For example, the first firm of my list does not have a registered patent, so I want run the code with the next firm id. At the end of the function I inserted

```
except Exception:
    print (f'CNPJ {pj} with problem. Check the list.')
    pass
```

but it was not enough. I really appreciate if someone can help me. Below is my code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Sun Sep 15 03:52:42 2019
Project: Patents
@author: caique
"""

# Create List
cnpj = ['00.000.100/0000-00', '76.487.032/0001-25', '46.068.425/0001-33', '00.348.003/0001-10', '17.217.985/0001-04']

# Create Function
def patente_pj(cnpj):

    import os
    import pandas as pd
    import selenium
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    from contextlib import suppress

    os.chdir("/home/caique/Desktop/Patentes INPI")

    # Chrome Headless
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
    # CAMINHO PARA O EXECUTÁVEL
    patentes = []
    try:
        for pj in cnpj:
                pj = str(pj).replace('.', '').replace('/', '').replace('  ', '').replace('-', '')
                driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r"/home/caique/Desktop/Patentes INPI/chromedriver")
                driver.get("https://gru.inpi.gov.br/pePI/jsp/patentes/PatenteSearchBasico.jsp")
                driver.find_element_by_link_text("Continuar....").click()
                driver.get("https://gru.inpi.gov.br/pePI/jsp/patentes/PatenteSearchBasico.jsp")
                driver.find_element_by_link_text("Pesquisa Avançada").click()
                destination_page_link = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='principal']/div[7]/button")
                destination_page_link.click()
                driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                    "//*[@id='principal']/div[7]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/font/input").send_keys(pj)
                driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                    "//*[@id='principal']/table[3]/tbody/tr[1]/td/font[2]/select/option[1]").click()
                driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='principal']/table[3]/tbody/tr[2]/td/font/input[1]").click()

                html_source = driver.page_source
                html_source
                soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source, 'lxml')
                tabela = soup.find_all("tr")[8]
                soup1 = soup.find_all("tbody")[1]
                soup2 = soup.find_all("tbody")[2]
                hits = len(soup2.find_all("a")) - 1

                linha1 = []
                for col in tabela.find_all("td"):
                    linha1.append(col.text)

                table_dados = []
                for i in range(0, len(soup1.find_all("b"))):
                    dict = {}
                    linha_teste = soup1.find_all("tr")[i]
                    dict[linha1[0]] = linha_teste.find_all("a")[0].text.replace('\n\t', '').replace('\n', '').replace('  ',
                                                                                                                      '')
                    dict[linha1[1]] = linha_teste.find_all("td")[1].text[19:29]
                    dict[linha1[2]] = linha_teste.find_all("b")[0].text.replace('\n\t', '').replace('\n', '').replace('  ',
                                                                                                                      '')
                    dict[linha1[3]] = linha_teste.find_all("font")[3].text.replace('\n\t', '').replace('\n', '').replace(
                        '  ', '')
                    table_dados.append(dict)

                desired_width = 700  # LARGURA
                pd.set_option('display.width', desired_width)
                pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 10)
                tabela_de_teste = pd.DataFrame(table_dados)
                driver.find_element_by_link_text("Próxima»").click()
                cont = 2
                for cont in range(1, int(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='tituloEResumoContextGlobal']/font/b[3]").text)):
                    html_source = driver.page_source
                    html_source
                    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source, 'lxml')
                    soup1 = soup.find_all("tbody")[1]
                    for i in range(0, len(soup1.find_all("b"))):
                        dict = {}
                        linha_teste = soup1.find_all("tr")[i]
                        dict[linha1[0]] = linha_teste.find_all("a")[0].text.replace('\n\t', '').replace('\n', '').replace(
                            '  ', '')
                        dict[linha1[1]] = linha_teste.find_all("td")[1].text[19:29]
                        dict[linha1[2]] = linha_teste.find_all("b")[0].text.replace('\n\t', '').replace('\n', '').replace(
                            '  ', '')
                        dict[linha1[3]] = linha_teste.find_all("font")[3].text.replace('\n\t', '').replace('\n',
                                                                                                           '').replace('  ',
                                                                                                                       '')
                        table_dados.append(dict)
                    if cont <-1+ int(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='tituloEResumoContextGlobal']/font/b[3]").text):
                        driver.find_element_by_link_text("Próxima»").click()
                print(pd.DataFrame(table_dados))
                driver.quit()
                tabela_final = pd.DataFrame(table_dados)
                patentes.append(tabela_final.to_csv('/home/caique/Desktop/Patentes INPI/CSV/patentes_'+pj+'.csv'))
    except Exception:
        print(f'CNPJ {pj} with problem. Check the list.')
        pass
    return patentes

# Run Function
patente_pj(cnpj)
```

Answer (score 4):

Put the `try ... except` statements into the start and end of each loop.

You may want to consider printing the error message when the exception occurs to debug better.